# Resaltar error en vba

Tags: excel, vba

Este código sirve para que salga un mensaje de error si no se introduce nada en según qué celdas.

Necesito que se marque en rojo esas mismas celdas para que los que introduzcan la información les sea mas fácil de ver qué celdas son. ¿Alguna idea?

```
On Error Resume Next
existe = False
For Each C In Range("B9:AD10,AE9,AE10,AE11,AA11,W11,S11,M11,I11,F11,D11,B11,B12:AD12,AE12,AE13,B13:AD13,N14,AE14,AE15,B15:AD15,I16,J16,AE16,W17,B17")
    If C.Value = "" Then
        celdas = celdas & " " & C.Address(False, False)
        existe = True
    End If
Next
If existe Then
celdas.Interior.Color = vbRed '(esta es la forma en la que lo he intentado)

    MsgBox "Falta informacion en las celdas : " & celdas
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Añade "C.Interior.Color = vbRed"dDespués del primer If. Te paso como quedaría:

```
On Error Resume Next
existe = False
For Each C In Range("B9:AD10,AE9,AE10,AE11,AA11,W11,S11,M11,I11,F11,D11,B11,B12:AD12,AE12,AE13,B13:AD13,N14,AE14,AE15,B15:AD15,I16,J16,AE16,W17,B17")
    If C.Value = "" Then
        C.Interior.Color = vbRed
        celdas = celdas & " " & C.Address(False, False)
        existe = True
    End If
Next
If existe Then
    MsgBox "Falta informacion en las celdas : " & celdas
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: no ha cambiado nada las celdas siguen en blanco

Comment: vale el problema es que al estar las celdas protegidas no se pinta pero al desbloquearlas si pero es raro porque las celdas que se tienen que pintar no estan protegidas sabes como seria para que funcione con celdas protegidas?

Comment: No se pueden hacer modificaciones sobre celdas protegidas. Para ello primero tienes que desproteger (sheet(nombrehoja).unprotect), luego hacer las modificaciones y por último volver a proteger la hoja (sheet(nombrehoja).protect).